# How to check admin user logged on front side in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, login, admin-user

Like title, I want check admin user logged in front end.

In a browser, if admin user logged then customer can't login.

All help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, so you want to check admin and customer?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel If customer logged, admin user can't login and if admin user logged, customer can't login!

Comment: Okay so it is default functionality but if you need condition with code I will give you

Comment: default functionality ? yes, of course i need!

Comment: Okay let me check and update you.

Comment: is it okay just I give code and you can manage it.

Comment: yes, dont worry!